# Nginx choosing wrong $document_root

Tags: php, nginx

On a simple configuration nginx seems to be picking a random configuration file's document root to set as the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] inside the PHP process it's attempting to fastcgi proxy to.

I've tried numerous configurations to try and scope the problem including nginx's debug log however to no avail

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.co.uk;
    index index.php;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.co.uk.error.log debug;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.co.uk.access.log;
    root /var/www/domain.co.uk;

    location / {
      try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain.co.uk/index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;        
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_pass  unix:/dev/shm/php.7.2.sock;        
    }
}
```

What happens is that the request picks a random other configuration and applies the document root from that to it. THe other configurations tend to have an `auto_prepend` line in the PHP part of the config that auto_prepends a config.php file to every request. The strange part os that the config.php from another random site (it's never the same site twice in a row) has some includes in it - one of which is an **autoloader**. The **autoloader** tries to load a file which does not exist (error below)

`2019/05/02 08:37:34 [error] 19105#0: *575827 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/domain.co.uk/resources/lib/class.autoloader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/www.anotherdomain.co.uk/config.php on line 84`

What this error is saying is that it's prepending the `config.php` file from `/var/www/www.anotherdomain.co.uk/config.php` which is ultimately causing the error chain.

I am absolutely lost on how to start debugging this, I've been at it for two whole days and am none the wiser!

As I say, most of the other site configs have the `auto_prepend` PARAM in the config so my question is really why is nginx picking one of those at random to apply to the config file in question?

If I change `fastcgi_params` to remove `$document_root` the problem goes away which tells me that nginx doens't know what the `$document_root` is at the time of the request for some really strange reason.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To aid debugging I changed the FPM socket that the configuration uses to a new one independant of any other config and the problem has compleetly gone away (thus far) This means that it's likely php7.2-fpm that's causing the error - possibly the opcache?

Comment: As soon as I put another config on the same socket file (`fastcgi_pass`) the problem starts happening again

Comment: So have you fixed this problem now?

Comment: No, I thought I had but if I add another site on the same PHP socket and refresh then the problem arises again. I really do think it's down to the opcache somehow but I think it's being fed the wrong `$document_root` from nginx

Comment: Please show the part of the config with the `auto_prepend_file`, I cant quite grasp how you are trying to dynamically change it at run time.

Comment: Also please note it is bad practice to use the same PHP-FPM process between different sites, you should ideally have a separate fpm pool for each website running under a separate user, preventing a compromised site from being able to read/edit the files of another site. This guide I made may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIwadOtwdaI

Comment: You set the document root in two places, once with the `root` statement, which is the value used by `fastcgi_params` and then explicitly in the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` value. Is there a reason you cannot use `$document_root/index.php`?

Comment: What is that `try_files $uri =404;` within the `location ~ \.php` for? I think it caused the nginx to server the file `$uri` and the first file happened to be `config.php`.

Comment: You mention that you are setting `auto_prepend_file`, where are you doing this and how?

Comment: @hcheung `try_files` is completely valid and recommended in the location block, it is used to validate the file actually exists on disk before trying to pass the filename to php for use.

Comment: `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file='/var/www/domain.co.uk/config.php'`

This is set in the PHP block, if I remove this line then the problem goes away...

Comment: I suspected as much, I will post an answer to your question shortly

Comment: @RichardSmith I don't see where I am setting `$document_root` in two places.

`SCRIPT_FILENAME` is not document_root. I've simply set it to a hard coded value for debugging purposes, normaly it's set to `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name`

Comment: @Geoffrey `try_files` within the `location /` is valid and required, but `try_files` within the location `location ~ .php` is not. It caused the nginx to serve the file it found instead of passing it to the backend.

Comment: @hcheung you are incorrect, please read the documentation on `try_files`, you provide it with a list of filenames to attempt, since the configuration states `$uri` and it's inside the `location` block for files ending in `.php`, the `$uri` will be the PHP filename. ie: for `example.com/abc.php`, the `$uri` would be `/abc.php`, since the next filename to try is `=404`, if the file `/abc.php` doesn't exist on disk it will return a 404 error. See: https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is due to a failure to understand how PHP-FPM operates. Each PHP process is long lived and reused, however for performance each process loads in it's ini config (including `PHP_VALUE` env vars) and any extensions it requires on the first request.

In your scenario you have two websites sharing the same PHP-FPM pool, lets call these "SiteA" and "SiteB", and each are configured the way you mentioned, using the PHP_VALUE environment variable with separate prepend files.

1. A user hits SiteA, PHP is not yet initialised, so it loads it's config, and the prepend file loaded and cached for use.
2. A user now hits SiteB, but now PHP is already initialized, so it continues using the existing loaded configuration, attempting to use SiteA's prepend file.

If you were to reverse this and hit SiteB first, then forever SiteB's prepend file would be loaded until you restarted the FPM pool.

To correct this you need to run a separate pool for each website, with a `auto_prepend_file` for each, ideally configured in the pool's config instead of by setting a Nginx environment variable. This is highly recommended anyway for security as it adds a level of isolation you would otherwise be missing.

I suggest you follow the guide I made here on an optimal, multi-user secure PHP+Nginx configuration and alter it to your requirements.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIwadOtwdaI

Note: this guide is part of a series from start to finish on how to setup a fully featured HTTP server from scratch, if you need more information check out the prior videos.

Edit2: Please note that this video needs an update, the usage of `try_files` is far better then the `if` usage described in the video. See: https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/

Comment: Is there no other way to do this aside running seperate pools?. Best practice or not there must be a way to tell the FPM cache to serve the correct file?

Comment: @JamesKipling no, nor should you. Remember that PHP-FPM forks and as such takes advantage of COW (Copy on write) semantics, the overhead of doing so is minimal.

Comment: does it use its own cache or the opcode cache to cache the `auto_prepend_file(s)`

I've hunted the internet and cannot find where this caching happens.

Comment: It has nothing to do with cache or opcache, you are missing the entire point of php-fpm... the setting you are trying to change is only settable at startup and only once. It's not intended to be changed dynamically. You're simply trying to misuse the feature.

Comment: Ok thanks.

Quick comment on your youtube video. You say there is no way to test a php-fpm config (https://youtu.be/NIwadOtwdaI?t=812). This is untrue You can do `path/to/php-fpm -t` and it will test your config similar to `nginx -t`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that tip, I was unaware of that feature.

Comment: Quick update to this. While the values are technically NOT cached they are remembered as the last value. What's happening is nginx is remembering there is an `auto_prepend` line and until that's ***unset*** or ***set*** to something else it uses the last value. It's not really a cache entry per-se, more of a "I am set until you unset me". One can get round it by simply unsetting it or setting it to a new value, this is why the other set parameters don't get effected (because they're set on every other request) but in my case the `auto_prepend` for this specific config was not happening!

Comment: This is still an abuse of the feature, PHP-FPM is not designed to operate this way and you WILL cause a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) where simultaneous requests can end up with the wrong environment variable set. Also this is NOT "nginx remembering", it's setting/unsetting a environment variable. Again I reiterate, do not do this!